# Getting an error during Sitecore 9 Installation

Tags: installation, sitecore

During Sitecore 9 installation , I am facing below error on line number 87 (i.e. last step )

> [WebDeploy]:[Path] C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy
>   V3\msdeploy.exe
>
> Error: Source does not support parameter called 'EXM Master DB Name'.
>   Must be one of (Application Path, Sitecore Admin New Password,
>   Database Server Name, Database Admin User Name, Database Admin User
>   Password, Core DB Name,Master DB Name, Web DB Name, Reporting DB Name,
>   XDB Reference Data DB Name, Experience Forms DB Name, Marketing
>   Automation DB Name, Processing Pools DB Name, Processing Tasks DB
>   Name, Core DB User Name, Core DB User Password,Master DB User Name,
>   Master DB User Password, Web DB User Name, Web DB User Password,
>   Reporting DB User Name, Reporting DB User Password, XDB Reference Data
>   DB User Name, XDB Reference Data DB User Password, Experience Forms DB
>   User Name, Experience Forms DB User Password, Marketing Automation DB
>   User Name, Marketing Automation DB User Password, Processing Pools DB
>   User Name, Processing Pools DB User Password, Processing Tasks DB User
>   Name, Processing Tasks DB User Password, Core Admin Connection String,
>   Master Admin Connection String, Web Admin Connection String,
>   Experience Forms Admin Connection String, Reporting Admin Connection
>   String, Processing Tasks Admin Connection String, Master Connection
>   String, Core Connection String, Web Connection String, XDB Reference
>   Data Connection String, Experience Forms Connection String, Reporting
>   Connection String, SOLR Connection String, XConnect Collection, XDB
>   Reference Data Client, XDB MA Connection String, XDB MA Reporting
>   Client, XDB MA Ops Client, Processing Pools Connection String,
>   Processing Tasks Connection String, XConnect Server Certificate
>   Validation Thumb print, XConnect Collection Certificate, XDB Reference
>   Data Client Certificate, XDB MA Reporting Client Certificate, XDB MA
>   Ops Client Certificate, Data Folder, Solr Core Index Name, Solr Master
>   Index Name, Solr Web Index Name, Solr Testing Index Name, Solr
>   Suggested Index Name, Solr FXM Master Index Name, Solr FXM Web Index
>   Name, Solr Marketing Asset Master Index Name, Solr Marketing Asset Web
>   Index Name, Solr Marketing Definitions Master Index Name, Solr
>   Marketing Definitions Web Index Name).
>
> Error count: 1.
>
> Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft
>   Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1) At
>   D:\sitecore9\sc9_install.ps1:87 char:1
>   + Install-SitecoreConfiguration @sitecoreParams
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

Anyone can help me with this ?

Comment: This question already has answer here https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9611/sitecore-9-update-1-installation-exm-master-db-name

Comment: Thanks Marek
Working fine now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Solution.
Need to refer correct JSON file for package

https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9611/sitecore-9-update-1-installation-exm-master-db-name